# MobileFirst 7.0 An error was encountered while processing the request from the application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Getting the error alert after direct update success and app try to reload the application.

Server version: 7.0.0.00.20151020-1831

Project WAR version: 7.0.0.00.20151020-1831

Adapter name: WLClientLogReceiver. Version: 7.0.0.00.20151020-1831

[image: Update Available]
[image: Error after direct update]

Server authenticationConfiguration setting

```
<customSecurityTest name="CustomAppAuthenticitySecurity">
            <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
```

Client error log: same error message in android and iOS while app try to reload after direct update.

> 2015-11-04 16:49:12.589 Direct[12642:47638] [TRACE] [WLNativeXHR] callback {"statusText":"Expected status code in (200-299), got 403","status":403,"headers":{"Pragma":"no-cache","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Keep-Alive":"timeout=10, max=100","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","P3P":"policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE\"","Date":"Wed, 04 Nov 2015 21:49:35 GMT","Content-Language":"en-US","Content-Length":"119","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate","Expires":"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"},"responseText":"/*-secure-\n{\"WL-Authentication-Failure\":{\"wl_authenticityRealm\":{\"reason\":\"App authenticity security check failed\"}}}*/","wlFailureStatus":"","callbackId":"WLNativeXHRPlugin119420831"}

Comment: That error belongs to Authenticity. Check your logs to see what is the failure.

Comment: Hi Adar, updated question with client log. If there is no update from the server, the application pass the app authenticity validation and works fine. After deploy a new WLAPP file in server for direct update its gives this error.

Comment: What are you talking about? Look at the log, it says that app authenticity failed! Also, decrease the size of the images you have embedded in the questions.

Comment: App authenticity is not failing at the first time. App is able to connect to the server and its pass the app authenticity validation.  Now just update the text in HTML file and build the environment. Deployed the WLAPP file to the MobileFirst server. In device kill the running app and relaunch. As expected getting the direct update, once its complete, Application try to reload the app and its falling the App Authenticity validation.  There is no change in signing key store, server settings, Client properties. I am using the sample code IBM info center, CustomDirectUpdate.zip for this testing.

Comment: You can try the sample code from info center for direct update with custom  app authenticity enabled on the mobile first server. Not sure why its failing after direct update .

Comment: Thanks Idan. Opened PMR - Waiting for their update. PMR#  08772,L6Q,000

Comment: Good. Please remove this question as I prefer not to have this duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this question is tracked as PMR #08772,L6Q,000 as there seems to be no workaround for the error (authenticity failure after Direct Update), other than disabling authenticity...